# How to add a custom exporter for capturing traces from opentelemetry?

Tags: .net, opentracing, opencensus

I have created a custom exporter by Implementing the SpanExporter class of OpenTelemetry.Trace.Export in .NET Core.

I need to configure the opentelemetry traces to use this as an exporter. I am not using any collector here I want to directly use this exporter in-process.

Earlier we were using Jaeger exporter as follows:

```
using (_tracerFactory = TracerFactory.Create(
                builder => builder.UseJaeger(o =>
                {
                    o.ServiceName = "TestJaeger2";
                    o.AgentHost = "localhost";
                })

))
```

I need to use the custom exporter inplace of JaegerExporter now, how to configure this?

Comment: Does https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet#implementing-your-own-exporter give you a start?

Comment: Yes @PeterBons Thanks a lot I was able to figure it out.

Comment: Care to share what you found?